# How to disconnect the public network by SL API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In SL portal I can select "disconnect" attribute from speed field. Do we have SL API to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to disconnect the network through the **setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed** method.

[SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed/) (for hardware servers)

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed/) (for virtual guests).

The speed values can only be 0 (Disconnect), 10, 100, or 1000. The new speed must be equal to or less than the max speed of the interface.

```
POST:

https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/111122/setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed

BODY:
{
    "parameters": [
        0
    ]
}
```

**Note:** Set **[userName]** and **[apiKey]** with your own data and the value **111122** with the ID of the virtual guest device